# Running an uberjar

Tags: java, jar, clojure, leiningen

I'm rather new to programming, so please excuse any obvious mistakes I'm making.

I have a clojure project, which runs fine, only when a (-main) is added to the end of the `clj file`. I have created a stand alone jar using `lein uberjar`. I am now trying to get this to run, using `java -jar [name of my jar].jar`

This returns the following error -  `Error: Unable to access jarfile condor-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`

I have seen some questions saying that a require a path and others which I do not.

How do I get this standalone to run?

Also my clojure project has multiple files which it uses as source code, how do I ensure that when I make the jar in the first place it is the right application which I am making? I feel like that is a stupid question, but it's one I don't know the answer to!

Thanks

**project.clj**

```
(defproject uberthing "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" 
  :description "FIXME: write description" 
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME" 
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License" :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"} 
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]] 
  :main ^:skip-aot uberthing.core 
  :target-path "target/%s" 
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

**core.clj**

```
(ns uberthing.core (:gen-class))

(defn -main "I don't do a whole lot ... yet." 
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

Comment: I forgot to add, as the .clj only runs when there is a  `(-main)` at the end. Whilst I am aware that this is not needed on my standalone, I don't know what should be in its place.

Comment: Can you please post your project.clj and the ns expression at the beginning of the .clj file with your -main function?

Comment: My project.clj 
 `(defproject uberthing "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot uberthing.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})`
 
 My core 
 ` (ns uberthing.core`
 ` (:gen-class))`

`(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!")) `

Comment: You have a few ` characters in your core file that shouldn't be there - if I remove them, "java -jar target/uberjar/uberthing ..." works fine. But how did your file end up being called condor, if the project is uberthing?

Comment: The project uberthing is to get to grips with getting a clojure project running the the java VM. Condor is due to the file then needing to run on HTCondor. I think my issue was in what to 'run' do I the path, i.e `java - jar target/` as before I was trying `java -jar snapshot

Comment: @WillBarnsley can you edit your question to include the project.clj and core.clj? It's important information and it's hard to read in your comment.

Comment: not entirely sure what i changed but its worked, thanks